# Is android Room database secure to store sensitive data?

Tags: android, security, android-room, reverse-engineering

I am working in a project where I have to fetch the data from the server to a local database. I was thinking about room database which is a part of android Jetpack components(I guess).I have searched a lot in stack overflow about if it is safe to store data in Room ? ,but none of them can satisfy me.Although nothing is safe and secure in internet but I just want to what are the possible ways to crack a room database ?

In short I just want to know if it is secure to store data in locally in Room database ? Please can someone tell me if Room database is safe or not ? Or how can Someone get a room database by reverse engineering ?

Answer (score 5):

Room store it's sqlite file in app's internal data directory so no other app can access (including the user as long as the phone is not rooted).

It should be fine for normal use cases. If you need extra layer of security you can use SqliteCipher to encrypt your database. You can use sqlcipher with room directly.

```java
final byte[] passphrase = SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(userEnteredPassphrase);
final SupportFactory factory = new SupportFactory(passphrase);
final SomeDatabase room = Room.databaseBuilder(activity, SomeDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
  .openHelperFactory(factory)
  .build();
```

for more info: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher#using-sqlcipher-for-android-with-room

Comment: Thanks Sujan, many many thanks for your explanation.I'm greatly satisfied with your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, please don't forget to accept answer it will make easier for someone else to find solution

Comment: I've voted and accepted your answer. One more thing, I would like to draw your attention here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62786976/13368093
Please have a look at this question.

Comment: I've some problem with your answer. Although at first I was thinking it will work. But can you please tell me what should I put  "userEnteredPassphrase"  here ? I mean what stands for "userEnteredPassphrase" ?

Comment: Can I replace your first line with this **final byte[] passphrase = "SomeString".getBytes();**

Comment: @Koushik I think it should work with String.getBytes().

Comment: Can you please write the complete code. Because I'm new in room and I'm pretty much confuse about this. Can you please give me a copy-paste solution.Please bro.

Comment: How to secure this userEnteredPassphrase? Because I encrypted this userEnteredPassphrase, I cannot open the Database.